# How to allow running blocked java plugins in browser using web driver

Tags: java, selenium, plugins, webdriver

I need help with my WebDriver script to handle Java Clients/tools.

For our web application we have special Java tool created which launches automatically when navigating to a special link.

After the page is launched, Firefox need permission to allow java (see capture screenshot). Notice there are 2 buttons: ":Continue Blocking" and "Allow".

After clicking the Allow, I get more option to allow and remember (see capture2)

How can I handle this in case in web driver.
I tried setting the browser profile, but for security reason browser always prompts me to allow java plugin.

can I even handle this in Selenium Web Driver.

Is there other tools that can handle this?

thanks in advance

[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqvQq.jpg)

[Capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI2Px.jpg)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Forgot one more thing, Maybe I can also click in the Activate Java link that displays in the Capture image, which is embedded : <embed id="deployJavaPlugin" type="application/java-deployment-toolkit" hidden="true">

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this from Selenium WebDriver by clicking on that dialog.
But there are at least 2 different ways to do it:

1) create a new Firefox Profile manually and configure it to allow Java Plugin (visit your site, allow and remember, etc).
Then, in your tests, create the FirefoxDriver with this existing profile.

2) use external tools that can be used specifically for this: Sikuli, Auto-it.